# Listing of the recent answers

Tags: support, answers

In Stack Exchange websites, the home page shows recent active posts (new question, new answer, new edit, reopened, closed etc.). In **Questions** page, the recent/active/bountied/.../(also unanswered) questions are listed.

Is there a way to list the recent answers? I would like to avoid opening each post to check if it has a new answer.

Comment: Hey there, why did you delete your "show off your hat" post, if I may ask?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the [search option](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/searching) `is:a` and sort on Newest: https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?tab=newest&q=is%3aa is a list of recent answers on this very site.

[image]